# Google Datalab is not working now

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-data

The easy-and-famous datalab create instance-name command is not longer working. We did not any change in project/apis/keys/ or any other google options.

The same cmd was ok yesterday and now:

```
user-used-yeserday@pruebaalexborrar:~$ datalab create alexborrarpurbea 
ERROR: gcloud crashed (BadStatusCodeError): HttpError accessing        
<https://sourcerepo.googleapis.com/v1/projects/pruebaalexborrar/repos
alt=json>:     
response: <{'status': '500', 'content-length': '109', 'x-xss-protection':     

'1;     mod
e=block', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'transfer-encoding':    
'chunked', 'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer', 'server': 'ESF', '-content-
encoding': 'gzip', 'cache-control': 'private', 'date': 'Wed, 19 Apr 2017 
09:08:43 G
MT', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'content-type': 'application/json;     
charset=UTF-8'}>, content <{
"error": {
"code": 500,
"message": "Internal error encountered.",
"status": "INTERNAL"
    }
}
>
```

When I use the same URL on my browser to get the error, I got other different error:

```
{
"error": {
"code": 401,
"message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected 
OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. 

See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
"status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
}
}
```

I guess the 401 error code is not related with the upper 501 from the `datalab create´ command...

I know google now is deploying new cloud release...

Anyone knows what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

There is a reported issue as [#37242989](https://issuetracker.google.com/37242989) at the issue tracker regarding this, so I suggest that you can add more details and star the issue there to get further updates from the related team working on this.